# Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UnknownError when listing Drives for a SharePoint site

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

When attempting to the list the drives for a SharePoint site, I recently began receiving a `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UnknownError` response.

The request and response is as follows:

**Request**:

```http
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<site_id>/drives?select=*,system
```

**Response**:

```http
request-id: 050894cc-a435-498a-ae0a-ead3d46924f9
client-request-id: 050894cc-a435-498a-ae0a-ead3d46924f9
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"East US","Slice":"SliceB","Ring":"NA","ScaleUnit":"000","Host":"AGSFE_IN_21","ADSiteName":"EST"}}

{
  "error":{
    "code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UnknownError",
    "message":"Unknown Error",
    "innerError":{
      "request-id":"050894cc-a435-498a-ae0a-ead3d46924f9",
      "date":"2017-12-06T12:38:44"
    }
  }
}
```

The same call was working earlier this week without any changes on my end.

I found a few posts from about a month ago that indicate this is possibly a regression on the MS side of things.

- [Microsoft Graph Exception code -1 starting this week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47179161/microsoft-graph-exception-code-1-starting-this-week/)
- [Microsoft Graph API for SharePoint in Python: Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UnknownError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47154944/microsoft-graph-api-for-sharepoint-in-python-microsoft-sharepoint-client-unknow)
- [MS Graph API Unknown Error when trying to get folder's children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47144300/ms-graph-api-unknown-error-when-trying-to-get-folders-children)

Is this a indeed a regression on the MS side? Is it a change in API behavior that I need to adjust for?

Answer (score 0):

This was indeed a regression that hit a limited number of scenarios. We've since fixed it so you shouldn't see the unexpected behavior any more.